# Help on getting code coverage for a Test class of a trigger

Tags: unit-test

I am having an issue getting code coverage for a trigger I wrote. 
My trigger is on Training_Project_Membership__c which is a child of Account, Program__c and Dasra module custom objects. Every Dasra Module has a CBM type (picklist) and its related Weight (Weight__c). Similarly Account and Program__c also have CBM type and weight. Whenever a new Training_Project_Membership__c is added, Trigger compares Dasra module's weight with the Account's weight and update the CBM type in account. Similar things happen with the program as well.
My trigger is working well but my test class is giving only 66% coverage.
Please help improve my test class. This is the first time I used custom settings in my code(to store Weigth and CBM type values).

Following is the trigger code-

```
trigger typeOfCB_SupportOnOrg on Training_Project_Membership__c (after insert, after update, after delete) {

Set<id> parentOrg = new Set<id>(); // declaring a set to store the id of the program Account's ID.
Set<id> parentProg = new Set<id>();
Decimal[] weight1 = new List<Decimal>();
CBM_Type__c settings = CBM_Type__c.getInstance('CB Type');
    String CBM_Portfolio = settings.CBM_Type_Portfolio__c;
    String CBM_GM = settings.CBM_Type_GM__c;
    String CBM_DSILP = settings.CBM_Type_DSILP__c;
    String CBM_DSIAP = settings.CBM_Type_DSIAP__c;
    String CBM_Others = settings.CBM_Type_Others__c;
    String CBMM_Weight_Portfolio = settings.Weight_Portfolio__c;
    String CBMM_Weight_GM = settings.Weight_GM__c;
    String CBMM_Weight_DSILP = settings.Weight_DSILP__c;
    String CBMM_Weight_DSIAP = settings.Weight_DSIAP__c;
    String CBMM_Weight_Others = settings.Weight_Others__c;


 If(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate)
   {   // Checking if trigger is Insert or Update.
        for(Training_Project_Membership__c child :[select Id, Dasra_Module__r.Weight__c, Organization__c, Program__c from Training_Project_Membership__c Where Id In: Trigger.New])
         { 
             If(child.Dasra_Module__r.Weight__c != 0)
                  { system.debug('child.Dasra_Module__r.Weight__c' + child.Dasra_Module__r.Weight__c);
                      parentOrg.add(child.Organization__c);
                         parentProg.add(child.Program__c);
                      weight1.add(child.Dasra_Module__r.Weight__c);              
                  }

         }
 system.debug('size-->' + parentOrg.size());
       system.debug('weight1-->'+weight1.size() + '--<>'+ weight1[0]); 
 List<Account> acct = new List<Account> ([Select Id, Name, Weight__c, Type_of_CB_support__c, (Select Id, Dasra_Module__r.Weight__c from Training_Project_Memberships__r)  from Account Where Id In : parentOrg]);
       If(acct.size()>0) {
       for(Account cbmm_Account : acct) 
           {
               If(cbmm_Account!= Null) {

            String d = cbmm_Account.Weight__c;
         Decimal[] OrgWeight = new List<Decimal>();
          for (Training_Project_Membership__c TPM : cbmm_Account.Training_Project_Memberships__r)
          {
              OrgWeight.add(TPM.Dasra_Module__r.Weight__c);
          }
         system.debug('OrgWeight' + OrgWeight);
         OrgWeight.sort();
         system.debug('OrgWeight' + OrgWeight);

         Decimal minOrgWeight = OrgWeight.get(0);

         cbmm_Account.Weight__c = String.valueOf(minOrgWeight); 


         system.debug('d-->' + d);
         system.debug('cbmm_Account.Weight__c-->' + cbmm_Account.Weight__c);


         if(cbmm_Account.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_Portfolio)
            {
                cbmm_Account.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_Portfolio;
            }
             else if(cbmm_Account.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_GM)
            {
                cbmm_Account.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_GM;
            }
             else if(cbmm_Account.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_DSILP)
            {
                cbmm_Account.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_DSILP;
            }
            else if(cbmm_Account.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_DSIAP)
            {
                cbmm_Account.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_DSIAP;
            }
             else if(cbmm_Account.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_Others) 
            {
                cbmm_Account.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_Others;
            }
        }
        }
    update acct;
        }
        system.debug('acct' + acct[0]);    

        List<Program__c> progList = new List<Program__c> ([Select Weight__c, Type_of_CB_support__c, (Select Dasra_Module__r.Weight__c from Training_Project_Memberships__r) from Program__c Where Id In : parentProg]);

        for(Program__c cbmm_Program : progList) 
        { String e = cbmm_Program.Weight__c;
         Decimal[] ProgWeight = new List<Decimal>();

         for (Training_Project_Membership__c CBMM : cbmm_Program.Training_Project_Memberships__r)
          {
              ProgWeight.add(CBMM.Dasra_Module__r.Weight__c);
          }
         system.debug('ProgWeight' + ProgWeight);
         ProgWeight.sort();
         system.debug('ProgWeight' + ProgWeight);
         If(ProgWeight.size()!= 0)
         {
         Decimal minProgWeight = ProgWeight.get(0);
         cbmm_Program.Weight__c = String.valueOf(minProgWeight);
         }

         //system.debug('d-->' + d);
         system.debug('cbmm_Account.Weight__c-->' + cbmm_Program.Weight__c);


         if(cbmm_Program.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_Portfolio)
            {
                cbmm_Program.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_Portfolio;
            }
             else if(cbmm_Program.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_GM)
            {
                cbmm_Program.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_GM;
            }
             else if(cbmm_Program.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_DSILP)
            {
                cbmm_Program.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_DSILP;
            }
            else if(cbmm_Program.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_DSIAP)
            {
                cbmm_Program.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_DSIAP;
            }
             else if(cbmm_Program.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_Others) 
            {
                cbmm_Program.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_Others;
            }

        }
    update progList;
        system.debug('progList' + progList[0]);    
   }
    parentOrg.clear();
    parentProg.clear();
   system.debug('parentOrg' + parentOrg);

    If(trigger.isDelete) //if trigger for delete DML operation
   {  system.debug('Old'+ trigger.old);
      //for(Training_Project_Membership__c child1 :[select Dasra_Module__r.Weight__c, Organization__c, Program__c from Training_Project_Membership__c Where Id In: trigger.old])
         for(Training_Project_Membership__c child1 : trigger.old)
         { system.debug('child.Dasra_Module__r.Weight__c' + child1.Dasra_Module__r.Weight__c);
             //If(child1.Dasra_Module__r.Weight__c != 0)
                   system.debug('child.Dasra_Module__r.Weight__c' + child1.Dasra_Module__r.Weight__c);
                      parentOrg.add(child1.Organization__c);
                         parentProg.add(child1.Program__c);
                      weight1.add(child1.Dasra_Module__r.Weight__c);                                  
         }
       system.debug('parentOrg' + parentOrg.size());
       system.debug('parentProg' + parentProg.size());
       system.debug('weight1' + weight1.size());

     List<Account> acct1 = new List<Account> ([Select Weight__c, Type_of_CB_support__c, (Select Id, Dasra_Module__r.Weight__c from Training_Project_Memberships__r)  from Account Where Id In : parentOrg]);
        for(Account cbmm_Account : acct1) 
        { String d = cbmm_Account.Weight__c;
         Decimal[] OrgWeight = new List<Decimal>();
          for (Training_Project_Membership__c TPM : cbmm_Account.Training_Project_Memberships__r)
          {
              OrgWeight.add(TPM.Dasra_Module__r.Weight__c);
          }
         system.debug('OrgWeight' + OrgWeight);
         OrgWeight.sort();
         system.debug('OrgWeight' + OrgWeight);

         If(OrgWeight.size()>0)
        {
            Decimal minOrgWeight = OrgWeight.get(0);

             cbmm_Account.Weight__c = String.valueOf(minOrgWeight);
        }

         /*system.debug('d-->' + d);
         system.debug('cbmm_Account.Weight__c-->' + cbmm_Account.Weight__c);*/

         if(cbmm_Account.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_Portfolio)
            {
                cbmm_Account.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_Portfolio;
            }
             else if(cbmm_Account.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_GM) 
            {
                cbmm_Account.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_GM;               
            }
             else if(cbmm_Account.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_DSILP) 
            {
                cbmm_Account.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_DSILP;                
            }
            else if(cbmm_Account.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_DSIAP) 
            {
                cbmm_Account.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_DSIAP;                
            }
             else if(cbmm_Account.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_Others)
            {
                cbmm_Account.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_Others;                
            }

        }
       update acct1;

     List<Program__c> ProgList1 = new List<Program__c> ([Select Weight__c, Type_of_CB_support__c, (Select Id, Dasra_Module__r.Weight__c from Training_Project_Memberships__r)  from Program__c Where Id In : parentProg]);
        for(Program__c cbmm_Program : ProgList1) 
        { String e = cbmm_Program.Weight__c;
         Decimal[] ProgWeight = new List<Decimal>();
          for (Training_Project_Membership__c TPM : cbmm_Program.Training_Project_Memberships__r)
          {
              ProgWeight.add(TPM.Dasra_Module__r.Weight__c);
          }
         system.debug('ProgWeight-->' + ProgWeight);
         ProgWeight.sort();
         system.debug('ProgWeight-->' + ProgWeight);
         if(ProgWeight.size()>0){
         Decimal minProgWeight = ProgWeight.get(0);
         cbmm_Program.Weight__c = String.valueOf(minProgWeight);}

         system.debug('e-->' + e);
         system.debug('cbmm_Program.Weight__c-->' + cbmm_Program.Weight__c);

        if(cbmm_Program.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_Portfolio)
            {                
                cbmm_Program.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_Portfolio;
            }
             else if(cbmm_Program.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_GM)
            {
                cbmm_Program.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_GM;
            }
             else if(cbmm_Program.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_DSILP)
            {                
                cbmm_Program.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_DSILP;
            }
            else if(cbmm_Program.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_DSIAP)
            {                
                cbmm_Program.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_DSIAP;
            }
             else if(cbmm_Program.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_Others) 
            {                
                cbmm_Program.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_Others;
            }         
        }
       update ProgList1;
   }
}
```

Test Class code-

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true) 
public class Test_typeOfCB_supportOnOrg 
{
    static testMethod void TypeOfSB_Support() {


         /*I tried to create an instance of custom settings here apart from annotation (SeeAllData = true)...when I use annotation only system gives me 66% test coverage otherwise it shows following error and 4% test coverage -
"System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, typeOfCB_SupportOnOrg: execution of AfterInsert

caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Trigger.typeOfCB_SupportOnOrg: line 7, column 1: []" */

CBM_Type__c settings = new CBM_Type__c();
        settings.Name = 'CB-Type';
        settings.CBM_Type_Portfolio__c = 'Portfolio';
        settings.CBM_Type_GM__c = 'Grant Management';
        settings.CBM_Type_DSILP__c = 'DSI-LP';
        settings.CBM_Type_DSIAP__c = 'DSI-AP';
        settings.CBM_Type_Others__c = 'Others';
        settings.Weight_Portfolio__c = '1';
        settings.Weight_GM__c = '2';
        settings.Weight_DSILP__c = '3';
        settings.Weight_DSIAP__c = '4';
        settings.Weight_Others__c = '5';
            insert settings;

        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Account', Type_of_CB_support__c = Null, Weight__c = '0', Organization_Type__c = 'Non-profit');
        insert acc;
        system.debug('acc-->' + acc);
        Program__c prog = new Program__c(Name = 'Test Prog', Organization__c = acc.Id, Type_of_CB_support__c = Null, Weight__c = '0');
        insert prog;

         Dissemination_Project__c objDisseminationProject = new Dissemination_Project__c();
         objDisseminationProject.Name = 'Test';
         objDisseminationProject.Themes__c = 'Strategic Giving';
         objDisseminationProject.CurrencyIsoCode = 'EUR';
         insert objDisseminationProject;



        Map<String,Id> mapRecType = new Map<String,Id>();
            List<RecordType> lstRecType = [Select Id, Name from RecordType];
         for(RecordType rec : lstRecType)
         {
          mapRecType.put(rec.Name,rec.Id);
         }
        //List<RecordType> lstRecType = [Select Id, Name from RecordType where SobjectType='Projects__c' And RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Capacity_Building_Module'];
        Projects__c DM = new Projects__c(Name = 'Test RProj', Related_Dissemination_Project__c = objDisseminationProject.Id, RecordTypeId = mapRecType.get('Capacity Building Module'), CBM_Type__c = 'Portfolio');
          insert DM; 
        Training_Project_Membership__c TPM = new Training_Project_Membership__c(Dasra_Module__c = DM.Id, Participant_Status__c = 'Accepted', Organization__c = acc.Id, Program__c = prog.Id);
          insert TPM;

        TPM = [select Name, Dasra_Module__r.Weight__c, Organization__c, Program__c from Training_Project_Membership__c where Id =: TPM.Id];

            acc = [select Type_of_CB_support__c, Weight__c from Account where Id =: TPM.Organization__c]; 
        acc.Weight__c = String.valueOf(TPM.Dasra_Module__r.Weight__c);

        If(acc.Weight__c == settings.Weight_Portfolio__c)
            {
                acc.Type_of_CB_support__c = settings.CBM_Type_Portfolio__c; //'Portfolio'; 
                //acc.Weight__c = settings.Weight_Portfolio__c;
                update acc;
            }
        else if(acc.Weight__c == settings.Weight_GM__c)
        {
            acc.Type_of_CB_support__c = settings.CBM_Type_GM__c;
            update acc;
        }

            prog = [select Type_of_CB_support__c, Weight__c from Program__c where Id =: TPM.Program__c];

            prog.Weight__c = String.valueOf(TPM.Dasra_Module__r.Weight__c);
        If(prog.Weight__c == settings.Weight_Portfolio__c){
            prog.Type_of_CB_support__c = settings.CBM_Type_Portfolio__c;
            update prog;
        }
         else if(prog.Weight__c == settings.Weight_GM__c)
         {
             prog.Type_of_CB_support__c = settings.CBM_Type_GM__c;
            update prog;
         }


            /*Training_Project_Membership__c TPM1 = [select Participant_Status__c, Organization__c, Program__c from Training_Project_Membership__c Where Id =: TPM.Id];
            TPM1.Participant_Status__c = 'Graduated';
            update TPM1;

            acc = [select Type_of_CB_support__c, Weight__c from Account where Id =: TPM.Organization__c];
           update acc;

               prog = [select Type_of_CB_support__c, Weight__c from Program__c where Id =: TPM.Program__c];
            update prog;*/

            Test.startTest();
            delete TPM;
            Test.stopTest();
            /*acc = [select Type_of_CB_support__c, Weight__c from Account where Id =: TPM.Organization__c];
            update acc;
            prog = [select Type_of_CB_support__c, Weight__c from Program__c where Id =: TPM.Program__c];
            update prog;*/



}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test class you are giving your custom setting name `settings.Name = 'CB-Type';` but in your code you are getting `CBM_Type__c.getInstance('CB Type');` you need to remove '-' from your test class custom setting record and it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Tushar..That works without using (seeAllData = True). But my code coverage is still 66%.

Comment: @AnkitGupta Which lines not getting covered in code.

Comment: else if(cbmm_Account.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_GM)
            {
                cbmm_Account.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_GM;
            }
          else if(cbmm_Account.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_DSILP)
            {
                cbmm_Account.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_DSILP;
            }
         else if(cbmm_Account.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_DSIAP)
            {
                cbmm_Account.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_DSIAP;
            }    @Tushar

Comment: @Tushar--- else if(cbmm_Program.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_GM)
            {
                cbmm_Program.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_GM;
            }
          else if(cbmm_Program.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_DSILP)
            {
                cbmm_Program.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_DSILP;
            }
         else if(cbmm_Program.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_DSIAP)
            {
                cbmm_Program.Type_of_CB_support__c = CBM_DSIAP;
            }
          else if(cbmm_Program.Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_Others)

Comment: under delete trigger part-- Decimal minOrgWeight = OrgWeight.get(0);
         
          cbmm_Account.Weight__c = String.valueOf(minOrgWeight);

Comment: To cover these lines of code you need to create test records which specify these condition like Account .Weight__c == CBMM_Weight_GM when you create the record it will automatically cover your code.

Comment: and everyone- I am trying to deploy this trigger to the Production but system is throwing following error.
'Invalid field CBM_Type_Portfolio__c for SObject CBM_Type__c'  both in trigger and test class.
Please help. @Tushar